# How to setup First Application in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

i am creating my first application in zf2.
i followed Zend Offical website [zf2 Skeleton Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html).i have downloaded the skeleton app from github as in in the given link.when i extract it and put that in my folder and run it its showing this Fatal Error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. 
 Run  `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in 
 D:\projects\zf2\zf2_app\init_autoloader.php:50 Stack trace: #0 D:\projects\zf2\zf2_app
 \public\index.php(9): require() #1 {main} thrown in D:\projects\zf2\zf2_app
 \init_autoloader.php on line 50
```

i dont know How to fix this??

and what about this?

```
To install Zend Framework 2 into our application we simply type:
  php composer.phar self-update
  php composer.phar install
```

where to type these commands?
Help me with my first ZF2 app

Comment: @downVoter = why? i really dont know thats why i come to SO.instead of helping you are dis discouraging me :(

Answer (score 18):

You should open a cmd window and change directory to your project. You then need to type the following:

```
php composer.phar install
```

This will install all the library dependencies for the Zend Skeleton Application - ZF2 in this case.

Comment: Ohh Thank you so much i ll certainly mark it TICK when i get enough reputation

Comment: But, I got the following error in command prompt. 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user2003356: That's a different problem. Quickly put your php.exe directory location to your system PATH variable.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Rob Allens answer i have good responses so far from Windows User who have less experience with the command line.

You may find my blog helpful, too: [Zend Framework 2 installation on Xampp for Windows](http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/)

Comment: Ohh Thats Great Sam .Excelent

Answer (score 3):

You may want to follow the following steps:

1. Download ZF2 Skeleton Application from Github.
2. Change directory where you want to install, and unzip the skeleton application.
3. Change directory to "ZendSkeletonApplication-master", and run the following:

   php composer.phar self-update
   php composer.phar install

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 2):

its seems like you have not Downloaded the zf2 :)
download it from here http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest#ZF2

extract the framework to vendor/ZF2. and you done :)
now browse to your app hope it showing No Exception.

Answer (score 2):

1.Enable LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so from your apache

2.Enable extension=php_openssl.dll from your php.ini

3.Install Composer from http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading. There are instructions for both Linux and windows.

4.Download skeleton project from github.( https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication and click the “Zip” button) to your htdocs.

5.Go to the directory where you have just downloaded the skeleton project.

6.Run php composer.phar install.This will download all the dependencies.

7.Go to http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html and create a virtual host accordingly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
DocumentRoot /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

8.Go to c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (Windows)or /etc/hosts(Linux) and add the following lines:
   `127.0.0.1               zf2-tutorial.localhost localhost`

9.Go to http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/ and you should see the welcome page.

Comment: Thanks, searched for hours and finally this worked. `SetEnv VAR "value"`

Answer (score 1):

How about making it easier @Rob Allen? When answering, so that other reader can save 24 hours to 1 minute !! I tried to make it easier from your answer as below:

```
1) httpd.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName site
 ServerAlias site
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/s/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/s/public>
    #AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

2) i did git clone git repo
$ ls
composer.json  composer.lock  composer.phar  config  data  db_bck  init_autoloader.php  LICENSE.txt  module  nbproject  public  README.md  vendor

3) I run and i get same error

4) I did now this

$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.0.6)
    Downloading: 100%         

    Skipped installation of bin/classmap_generator.php for package zendframework/zendframework: name conflicts with an existing file
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing doctrine/common (Doctrine\Common >=2.1 for annotation features)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ext-intl (ext/intl for i18n features)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing pecl-weakref (Implementation of weak references for Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendpdf (ZendPdf for creating PDF representations of barcodes)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha (ZendService\ReCaptcha for rendering ReCaptchas in Zend\Captcha and/or Zend\Form)
Generating autoload files


5) It works now
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have already downloaded the GIT file
Below commands are for windows :

1) Go to the respective folder
2) run the command -> composer update
3) That should let you install and choose optional modules
4) Finally -> php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t .\public .\public\index.php

With this you should be able to access the index page at http://localhost:8080/